# $(document).foundation(); not working

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation

I try to get my elements, that I load via ajax back to work but when I try to reinitialize the events on them, it simply doesn't work.
I tried to insert `$(document).foundation();` on different places in my code but nope :(

Here an example:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'dashboard/ajax/links/get',
        method: 'post',
        data: {
            _token: $('input[name=_token]').val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('.links-container').html(data);
            $(document).foundation();
        }
    });
```

Any ideas?

**Update**

Another example

```
// open edit link modal
$('.item-link-edit').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // get item id
    var id = getItemId(this);
    // open modal and load content
    $('#edit-link-modal').foundation('reveal','open',{
        url: 'dashboard/ajax/links/modals/edit',
        data: {
            id: id
        },
        success: function() {
            setTimeout(function(){
                $(document).foundation();
                console.log('reinit');
            },1000);
        }
    });
});
```

still not working :/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use reflow if you add new content to the DOM.

```
$(document).foundation('reflow');
```

Reflow will make Foundation check the DOM for any elements and re-apply any listeners to them. If you dont want to reflow everything you can specify the module you want to re-apply;

```
$(document).foundation('orbit', 'reflow'); // orbit, for an example
```

Further documentation can be found here:
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascript.html

Comment: tried that already but it did not work in my case ... donno why :( but thx anyway :)